# How to extract digits from a string and use them to extract from a YAML file

Tags: ruby, integer, yaml

I'm trying to extract integers from a string and use them to scan through a YAML file like so:

```
FORMS = YAML.load_file('../email/lib/lists/form_links.yml')

def get_form(form)
  form_num = form.scan(/\d+/)
  data = FORMS['esd_forms'][form_num]
  begin
    if data != nil
      "Form link: #{data}"
    else
      raise StandardError
    end
  rescue StandardError
    "** Form: #{form} is not a valid form name **"
  end
end
```

YAML file:

```
esd_forms:
  1: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-1.pdf'
  2: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-2.pdf'
  3: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-3.pdf'
  4: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-4.pdf'
  5: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-5.pdf'
  6: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-6.pdf'
  7: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-7.pdf'
  8: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-8.pdf'
  9: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-9.pdf'
  10: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-10.pdf'
  11: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-11.pdf'
  03: 'http://labornet.com/itc/OCIO-IT-03.pdf'
  07: 'http://labornet.com/itc/OCIO-IT-07.pdf'
  10: 'http://labornet.com/itc/OCIO-10.pdf'
  13: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-13.pdf'
  14: 'http://labornet.com/itc/ESD-14.pdf'
```

When I do this I get an error:

```
wrong argument type Array (expected Regexp)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. At first I thought it was because the program was returning an array instead of a string, so I tried it in IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> form = 'esd-2'
=> "esd-2"
irb(main):002:0> form_num = form.scan(/\d+/)
=> ["2"]
irb(main):003:0> puts form_num
2
```

To me, it seems like I'm doing this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How you call your `get_form` function? What line does the error address exactly?

Comment: When asking about code you've written, it's very important that we be able to duplicate the problem without having to write code to test, otherwise we can accidentally change the problem and provide answers that don't fit or help. We can piece it together based on your IRB session, but forcing us to do so slows our ability to help you, wasting time for us, you and others who have questions in the queue. Read "[mcve]" and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html which discuss how to ask these sort of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan) returns all the occurrences in the String that matches the regular expression, in an array.

You see in your irb session when you execute `form_num = form.scan(/\d+/)`, it actually returns an array with 1 element `["2"]`.

If you want to return the first matched segment, you can use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
form = 'esd-2'
form_num = form[/\d+/]
#=> "2"
```

Besides, if you need to examine what is stored in an variable, `p` will be a better choice than `puts`. And irb actually use `p` to output the expression result by default as you see in your irb session.

```
form = 'esd-2'
form_num = form.scan(/\d+/)
puts form_num
#=> 2
p form_num
#=> ["2"]
```

Comment: That makes sense, I do have a question though. How come it outputs the `2` when I call `puts form_num` in `irb`?

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome if `puts` is called with an array, it will output each element in the array line by line.

Comment: It's still outputting `** Form: esd-2 is not a valid form name **`

Comment: I'd recommend being a bit more specific in the regex used to retrieve the number by using `\d+$`. Doing so will avoid accidentally grabbing numbers inside the filename (`'a1-2'[/\d+/] # => "1"`), and will only retrieve trailing ones (`'a1-2'[/\d+$/] # => "2"`). (It's not smart to assume you'll _never_ see such filenames.) Also, anchoring the expressions using `$` or `\z` or `\Z` tells the regular expression engine to not waste time looking through the entire string for a digit, but instead only look at the end. The speed-up, especially over long strings or multiple lookups, can be drastic.

Comment: @theTinMan Do you think it's actually necessary to make a more complex regex if the filenames are not going to change? I'm not trying to say you're wrong because I completely agree with you, however I think that for this certain aspect a more complex regular expression would be a bit of overkill

Comment: Adding a trailing anchor makes it trivially more complex, but it also makes it faster and more bullet-proof. Gaining speed and robustness by adding a single element seems like a major win. So, while it's not _necessary_, it's certainly desirable, and in the long run might turn out to be very expedient if digits turn up in the filenames. From many years working in development I've learned to program defensively.